# How to get overall cluster health via REST api?

Tags: rest, couchbase

Using Couchbase v4.0.0-4051 I see how to get individual node status via the REST api. I don't see in the docs how I can get the same health status for the overall cluster. Is there a way to get this information from the REST API?

Comment: http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/admin/CLI/cbhealthchecker_tool.html Did you checked this already ? In options section it says `Specific bucket on which to report. The default is all buckets.` and see the example below. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, I did see that but that seems to require the use of the cbhealthchecker command-line tool. I had hoped to use the REST api.

Comment: I checked the cli tool source code, I think the related part is https://github.com/couchbase/healthchecker/blob/a43acce50fe273772205270f41a6f2a13ea6a7b5/analyzer.py#L89  here. They also getting node information one by one. I think there is no option to get overall. But you may implement this code for your need.  Check this also https://github.com/couchbase/healthchecker/blob/master/collector.py#L137